# Can I include another university's name in my SOP?

Tags: masters, statement-of-purpose

I am writing my SOP for MSc in computer science, in a paragraph, I'm explaining about things I did to learn more about the field of study I am interested in.

Is it alright to write that I watched a course from MIT to learn more about something? Or if you were in my place you would rather only tell that you watched a course about something without telling exactly what course of which university?

This course is available on YouTube and is kind of famous for learning deep learning, that's why I wrote from which university it is.

Comment: Leaving as a comment since it doesn't match your title question, but "I watched a YouTube video" is not interesting enough for your SOP.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- It's not a youtube video; it's a complete course that has been shared on youtube. http://introtodeeplearning.com/

Comment: When applying to the University of Michigan, it's OK to mention other universities, except Ohio State.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason why you can't mention the name of whoever created such a course, but I caution you to write an SoP that is better aligned with its intention. It isn't about the past or your accomplishments. The CV is for those kinds of things.

The SoP is entirely future directed about your plans for study and thereafter. It is about answering the questions about what you want to do and why. It isn't a mistake to use some things from the past as "direction setters" but don't spend many words on that. "The X course offered by Y has led me to focus on Z and my current intention is to.... future stuff". Don't spend long sentences or especially paragraphs on such things, but some phrases can work showing motivation.

So, your first paragraph here is the right idea, just don't overdo that but focus on plans. Watching a video course isn't an accomplishment, of course, as mentioned in a comment, but if it is a motivator and you state it that way you should be fine.